# Finding a function with given plot

Tags: real-analysis

I’m trying to plot this function using tikz. It is possible to make a point by point plot, but i was guessing what piecewise function this plot refers to? If anyone has an idea or has a function which is close to this. [image]

Comment: I think it's fine for math.stackexchange; the OP is asking for a mathematical function whose graph looks like this.

Comment: Exactly @GregMartin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is in the ballpark:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x+5+\frac{4}{x-1}, & \text{if }x<-1, \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(x^3-3 x\right)+1, & \text{if }-1<x<1, \\
 -\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if }1<x<3, \\
 \frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{1+\sqrt{x-3}}, & \text{if } x>3.
\end{cases}
$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Greg. This function works.